# Clearing existing Tezbox Ledger Nano s

Tags: ledger, tezbox

Hello I have set up Tezbox and generated kt1 address and have . However just saw a youtube vid that say I need to clear this in order to link my ledger nano s.  what exactly does clear mean? and what exactly do I do?  also will this work with ledger blue?

Thanks

Comment: meant to say I have tz in tezbox

Comment: Welcome to Tezos Stack Exchange! please edit your question as some sentences are not even complete. Remove the comment and just make your question clear. Please provide the link to the video you used etc.. in order to make your question as intelligible as possible! That's the best way to increase the chances someone will be able to answer to you!

Answer (score 2):

When you generate a webwallet in TezBox, it is recorded in your browser. This is why when you go again to the page you have a "Welcome Back" message and just have to enter your password. You have a "Clear TezBox" link at the bottom of this page to say that you don't want to interact with the last used webwallet but an other (that you will create or restore).
You can always restore this wallet later with your mnemonic words.

Beware, **make sure you have noted your mnemonic words** and no just the password before clearing the wallet.

Note that if you want to avoid having to restore the existing, you can open TezBox in an other browser or in a private session of the same browser (but in that case, the wallet won't be memorized). This method also allows you to use two webwallet at the same time if needed.

The Tezos application is sadly not yet available for Ledger Blue (and it is not sure it will).

Comment: I don't have a 'clear TezBox' message on my Welcome or Portfolio screen in Ledger Live. Where is it please?